# Linq Query ToList not putting data into a list, but rather a one element list

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following query (which is nested in a larger query):

```
PaymentType = (from paymenttype in offer.Elements(myns + "paymentTypes")
               select paymenttype.Value).ToList()
```

myns is an XNamespace type

the XML tree looks like

```
<offer>
    <paymentTypes>
        <paymentType>One String</paymentType>
        <paymentType>Another string</paymentTYpe>
    </paymentTypes>
</offer>
```

PaymentType is defined as:

```
List<string> PaymentType = new List<string>();
```

When my code executes, what I am seeing is a single item created:

```
PaymentType[0] = "OneStringAnotherString"
```

and not

```
PaymentType[0] = "OneString"
PaymentType[1] = "AnotherString"
```

I can't sort out what I am doing wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at it in the debugger, it's easier to tell that what you're getting back is the paymentTypes element.  If you know there's only one, the simplest change is to add .Elements() onto the end to get the children:

```
        var results = (from paymenttype in offer.Elements("paymentTypes").Elements()
                       select paymenttype.Value).ToList();
```

That gets you the 2 strings you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `Value` of `<paymentTypes>` in your example is `"One StringAnother string"`.

You need to select the `Value` from each `<paymentType>` individually:

```
var query = from paymenttype in offer.Element(myns + "paymentTypes")
                                     .Elements(myns + "paymentType")
            select paymenttype.Value;

List<string> PaymentType = query.ToList();
```

Or, if there are multiple `<paymentTypes>`, the `Value` from each `<paymentType>` in each `<paymentTypes>`:

```
var query = from paymenttypes in offer.Elements(myns + "paymentTypes")
            from paymenttype in paymenttypes.Elements(myns + "paymentType")
            select paymenttype.Value;

List<string> PaymentType = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, with the nested query, I couldn't do the first part...however, your two "from" statements is what I needed.  That solved it!!

Answer (score 0):

This will find all paymentType elements

```
var paymentTypes = (from paymentType 
                    in offer.Descendants(myns + "paymentType") 
                    select paymentType.Value).ToList();
```